# Stack Bragger (facebook app to post questions badges)

Tags: app, python, facebook

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image]

### About

Stack Bragger lets you brag to your Facebook friends whenever you ask new questions or earn new badges at StackOverflow, SuperUser or ServerFault.

I was looking for a weekend project and found out that stackoverflow api was released so I thought I'd make a small facebook app. I originally just wanted to post to FB whenever I got a badge, something like how PSN accounts automatically post Trophies to FB. It also posts questions you ask so that any friends you have on facebook not already using stackoverflow might want to help answer :D

#### License

Um, I haven't really thought about it. Should I release the source? Suggestions for license to use? [will update this later]

#### Link

To add the app to your facebook:
http://apps.facebook.com/stackfb/

#### Platform

The web!

### Contact

http://twitter.com/roytang

http://roytang.net/

### Code

Stack Bragger is powered by Python/Google App Engine.

Comment: I was wondering when somebody would make a facebook app.

Comment: @Kevin: Sorry. I'm not trying to be spammy. I was content with just a small note in the "How do I list my app here?" page, but someone rolled that one back. My intentions are honest - I have nothing to gain from people listing apps there. Everyone has something to gain - they get a concise list of all the apps - and access to bug reporting tools. (Which is not available on StackApps.)

Comment: Someone has posted a bug report to your app on StackList.

Comment: Why other beta stack exchange are not listed in this app?

Comment: License idea... [this](http://quickmediasolutions.com/unicorn/).

Comment: This application does not yet support secure browsing (HTTPS) :/